# Mysql use stored procedure results multiple times within a query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a stored procedure in my MySQL db, working fine.

However, since i have to call the same procedure 3 times in the same query with the same parameters, it woulb be a nice performance improvement if i could use the result of the first call instead of subsequent calls.

**Edit: changed the example because it was oversimplified, misleading replies**

I have to tables: products, and prices - prices change depending on the time of the year, and on payment mode,so structure is: (id, product_id, date_from, date_to, price_mode_1, price_mode_2, price_mode_3)

Example:

what i do now is

```
SELECT products.*, 
       get_a_quote(products.id,date_to,date_from, quantity_mode_1,quantity_mode_2,quantity_mode_3) 
  FROM peoducts 
 WHERE get_a_quote(products.id,date_to,date_from, quantity_mode_1,quantity_mode_2,quantity_mode_3)  >0 
ORDER BY 
       get_a_quote(products.id,date_to,date_from, quantity_mode_1,quantity_mode_2,quantity_mode_3) 
LIMIT 10
```

what i want to do is

```
SELECT products.*, 
       get_a_quote(products.id,date_to,date_from, quantity_mode_1,quantity_mode_2,quantity_mode_3)  into quote
  FROM peoducts 
 WHERE quote  >0 
ORDER BY 
       quote
LIMIT 10
```

Is this possible?

**Edit: function code **

```
FUNCTION `get_a_quote`(`productid` INT, `startDate` SMALLINT, `endDate` SMALLINT, `mode_1_quantity` SMALLINT, `mode_2_quantity` TINYINT, `mode_3_quantity` TINYINT) RETURNS smallint(6)
BEGIN
declare totalprice,p_1,p_2,p_3 smallint;
SELECT price_1,price_2,price_3 into p_1,p_2,p_3 FROM pricing WHERE id=productid and ((startDate between date_from and date_to) and (endDate between date_from and date_to));
if p_3 is null then
    set mode_2_quantity=mode_3_quantity+mode_2_quantity;
    set mode_1_quantity=mode_1_quantity+(4*mode_3_quantity);
    set p_3=0;
    set mode_3_quantity=0;
end if;
if p_2 is null then
    set mode_1_quantity=mode_1_quantity+(3*mode_2_quantity);
    set p_2=0;
    set mode_2_quantity=0;
end if;
if mode_1_quantity>0 and p_1 is null then
    return 0;
end if;
set totalprice = p_1*mode_1_quantity+p_2*mode_2_quantity)+p_3*mode_3_quantity);
RETURN totalprice;
END
```

Thanks everybody

Comment: [learn variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Can you put the entire SP code? Is the value total the value you want to store in a variable?

Comment: You're talking about functions, not procedures. Different story...

Comment: This will be phenomonally inefficient even with a single call - it would likely be a lot more appropriate to unroll the application logic from the function into the query itself.

Comment: I know, it's a function, my mistake. The problem is, it can't be unrolled into a query, or a join, or anything else. The only other way to do this would be to move the application logic in the function to php, but this looks way worse to me. So why are you saying even a single call would be inefficient? Are functions that bad in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT customers.*, 
           totalOrders (customers.id) AS total
      FROM customers
) AS t 
 WHERE total >0 
ORDER BY 
       total 
LIMIT 10
```

However, I wouldn't use a stored function for this. It's bound to have incredibly bad performance.

I'd use a JOIN so that I only fetch customers who have more than zero orders.

Comment: it has to be a function, it'n not just a sum like the name would suggest but has some IFs and some more maths too. So, do you think this derived table would be a performance increase over the 3 function calls i'm using now?

Comment: been testing with php's microtime for a while,your solution is about 30% more efficient than mine. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To me it semantically looks like you are adding a new, dependent column on the table. For which you could use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT customers.*, 
   get_a_quote(products.id,date_to,date_from, quantity_mode_1,quantity_mode_2,quantity_mode_3) AS total
FROM customers;
```

Then you can simply use it in your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM v
WHERE total >0 
ORDER BY 
    total 
LIMIT 10;
```

But then again what your function is doing might be better implemented using a JOIN on your tables, something like:

```
SELECT customers.*, 
       SUM(orders.value) 
FROM
    customers
    JOIN orders ON
         customers.id=orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY customers.id
HAVING SUM(orders.value)  >0 
ORDER BY 
    SUM(orders.value) 
LIMIT 10;
```

can you show us your function code?

Comment: posted more info, i don't think it can be done with a view as the function results vary depending on the request, it's not a simple total.

Comment: I totally don't see why it cannot be done with a view: can you try to run my VIEW definition and the following query using the view, and tell us what error message you get?

Comment: It's not that i'd get an error, it's just that this way i'd have to create a different view every time a user wants a quote, SELECT it, then drop it when he wants a different quote. This seems even less efficient than the 3 function calls i'm doing now, am i wrong?

Comment: It is difficult to guess what exactly your code is doing without seeing the body of your function. That said, you could also have another, wrapper function, that does all the work. Doesn't seem simpler than your original query though. -- What @symcbean is concerned about that in the best case your function is called once (if not 3 times) per each row. That is why the body of the function is relevant.